# How to stop the following setInterval() in jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

The code below moves an image from top of the screen to the bottom. I want this `setInterval()` function to stop once `y==-100` but I'm not sure how...

```
var image = $('.background');
var y = 0;
setInterval(function() {
  if (y == -100) {
    //don't know what to add here
  }
  image.css('background-position', '0 ' + y + 'px');
  y--;
}, 100);
```

I think I need to use `clearInterval` but I don't know what to return.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can store the interval's id when calling `setInterval` and then invoke `clearInterval` with that specific interval's id:

```js
var image = $('.background');
var y = 0;
var intervalId = setInterval(function() {
  if (y === -100) {
    clearInterval(intervalId);
  }
  image.css('background-position', '0 ' + y + 'px');
  y--;
}, 100);
```

```css
.background {
  background-image: url('//placehold.it/200');
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="background"></div>
```

Comment: Thanks for the anonymous downvote... even though I posted first and actually provided an example.

Answer (score 4):

You need to store the return value from `setInterval`, which you can then pass to `clearInterval`. The returned value is an opaque reference to the interval, so you shouldn't use it for anything else.

```
var image = $('.background');
var y=0;
var interval = setInterval(function(){
  if(y == -100) {
      clearInterval(interval);
  }
  image.css('background-position', '0 ' + y + 'px');
  y--;
}, 100);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do this:

```
var image = $('.background');
var y=0;
var interval = setInterval(function(){
    if(y == -100) {
        clearInterval(interval);
    }
    image.css('background-position', '0 ' + y + 'px');
    y--;
}, 100);
```